# How to find which elements of one set are in another set?

Tags: r

I have two sets: A with columns x,y, and B also with columns x, y.
I need to find the index of the rows of A which are inside of B (both x and y must match).
I have come up with a simple solution (see below), but this comparison is inside of the loop and `paste` adds much more extra time.

```
B <- data.frame(x = sample(1:1000, 1000), y = sample(1:1000, 1000))
A <- B[sample(1:1000, 10),]
#change some elements
A$x[c(1,3,7,10)] <- A$x[c(1,3,7,10)] + 0.5

A$xy <- paste(A$x, A$y, sep='ZZZ')
B$xy <- paste(B$x, B$y, sep='ZZZ')
indx <- which(A$xy %in% B$xy)
indx
```

For example for a single observation an alternative to `paste` is almost 3 times faster

```
    ind <- sample(1:1000, 1)
    xx <- B$x[ind]
    yy <- B$y[ind]

    ind <- which(with(B, x==xx & y==yy))
    # [1] 0.0160000324249268 seconds
    xy <- paste(xx,'ZZZ',yy, sep='')
    ind <- which(B$xy == xy)
    # [1] 0.0469999313354492 seconds
```

Comment: If the columns you are matching on are integer or character valued, the `data.table` package might offer a solution.  It's much faster for many matching and indexing type operations.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `merge()` to do the matching for you?

```
A$id <- seq_len(nrow(A))
sort(merge(A, B)$id)
# [1] 2 4 5 6 8 9
```

**Edit:**

Or, to get rid of *two* unnecessary sorts, use the `sort=` option to `merge()`

```
merge(A, B, sort=FALSE)$id
# [1] 2 4 5 6 8 9
```

Comment: @ilya This is better. You could probably also do something like `which(tail(duplicated(rbind(B,A)),nrow(A)))`, but that may be slow.

Comment: That works, but unfortunately there is no saving in time. 0.0309 sec for paste, vs 0.0469 sec for this method. I'm working on simulation project. Approx 40 mins of real life took me 24 hours. I'm trying to improve performance. I'm down to 9 hours. From profiling I can see that this part takes a lot of time, so I'm trying to find fast alternative.

Comment: Well, there may still be time savings. I don't need to do paste on B. This may save me time. I will do more testing

Comment: Yeah -- using `merge()` for this one side effect has to be overkill, if you're after speed.  That said, the code in `merge.data.frame()` might be a good source of ideas. It's authors probably grappled with just the questions of speed that you're facing right now. Do let us know what you find!

Comment: Somehow this sounds like the sort of problem that hash tables are supposed to solve quickly.  Unfortunately, all I know about hash tables is their name.  Can anyone help here?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- I agree. `match()`, for one, **uses** hash tables, but the calculated table isn't persistent. If you keep looking things up in the same table, you lose the benefit. Chambers references this in [this passage](http://books.google.com/books?id=UXneuOIvhEAC&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=chambers+match+hash+table+environment&source=bl&ots=2boAsR-UEA&sig=TPqpjA3iKfPcZOLVixmsdizn2Co&hl=en&ei=UW2oTsi-NcqPiAL-zNS5Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) of his book, going on to say that environments may offer a solution. I wish I understood this better.

Comment: @ilya: If it is taking 24 hours to run, then you may want to post a more representative example of what's being run.  I assume it's not the same as the example (24 * 3600 * 60 of these matches is a little odd).  If they're done in bulk, you could at least do a multicore version, using `foreach`.